# Injectivity of post-composition operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, mg.metric-geometry, metric-spaces, embeddings

Let $X$, $Y_1,Y_2$, and $Z$ be separable metric spaces.  Let $C(X,Y)$ be the topological space of continuous functions from $X$ to $Y$ equipped with its [compact-open topologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact-open_topology).  Fix a continuous functions:
$$
\begin{aligned}
F: X\times Y_2 & \rightarrow Z\\
f: Y_1 &\rightarrow Y_2
\end{aligned}
$$
Are the necessary and sufficient conditions on $F$ and on $f$ characterizing when the induced map:
$$
Y_1\ni y \mapsto F(\cdot ,y)\in C(X,Z),
$$
is injective and bi-Lipschitz?